# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\t20.1103\t17.00\n'

Tags: python

I am running a script that was given to me by someone else, but I keep getting the following error:

```
line 144, in <module>
    ID=int(afields[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\t20.1103\t17.00\n'
```

The error comes from this section of code:

```
while altlat and tminM and tmaxM:
        afields=altlat.split(' ')
        tmifields=tminM.split(' ')
        tmxfields=tmaxM.split(' ')

    ID=int(afields[0])
    y= float(afields[1])
    z=float(afields[2])
```

Where altlat is read from a .txt file:

```
ifh0=open(infilepath + '\\' + 'lat_alt_hainan.txt', "r")
zy_header_line=ifh0.readline()
altlat=ifh0.readline()
```

lat_alt_hainain.txt looks like this:

```
POINTID lat alt
1   20.1103 17.00
2   20.0269 1.00
3   20.0269 16.00
4   20.0269 17.00
5   20.0269 5.00
6   20.0269 5.00
```

etc...

so the first column is called using INT, the other two using FLOAT. This is where the error appears. The creator of the script told me that formatting the .txt file in excel to number format, after which the error dissapears, but I have done this and the error is still there. I then thought it might be because the .txt file uses '.' as decimal separator, while my computer uses ',', but I changed that and the error still comes up. Do you know any other way to prep a .txt file to be read by Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are tminM and tmaxM defined?

Comment: It dose not come under int or float so this error is printed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to split by all whitespaces, you should use - `string.split()` without any parameters.

Example -

```
while altlat and tminM and tmaxM:
        afields=altlat.split()
        tmifields=tminM.split(' ')
        tmxfields=tmaxM.split(' ')

    ID=int(afields[0])
    y= float(afields[1])
    z=float(afields[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to split the lines read / imported using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as stated in [this answer given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31134253/3991125).

However I want to show an alternative approach, since you mentioned that your data comes out of Excel.

I would suggest using Python's standard [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) module to read your data from file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import csv

with open('foo.csv') as csvfile:
    line = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    line.next() # skip header line
    for row in line:
        ID = int(row[0])
        lat = float(row[1])
        lon = float(row[2])

        print('ID: {}, Lat: {}, Lon: {}'.format(ID, lat, lon))
```

Whereas `foo.csv` as the following structure (Semi-colon as column delimiter, Dot as decimal delimiter):

```
POINTID;lat;alt
1;20.1103;17.00
2;20.0269;1.00
3;20.0269;16.00
4;20.0269;17.00
5;20.0269;5.00
6;20.0269;5.00
```